# The way to show equivalence of two objectives in Conjugate Gradient Methods

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I am studying Numerical Optimisation and now it comes to Conjugate Gradient Methods

Intuitively, I can accept

"Solving $Ax=b$ is equivalent to solving $min_x~\phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^\top Ax-b^\top x$"

How to formally show that these two are equivalent?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, it is assumed in this context that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Let $x_*$ denote a solution to $Ax = b$. Note that
$$
\begin{align}
x^TAx &= (x - x_* + x_*)^TA(x - x_* + x_*)
\\ &= (x-x_*)^TA(x-x_*) + x^TAx_* + x_*^TAx + x_*^TAx_*
\\ &= (x-x_*)^TA(x-x_*) + 2x_*^TAx + x_*^TAx_*
\\ &= (x-x_*)^TA(x-x_*) + 2(Ax_*)^Tx + x_*Ax_*
\\ &= (x-x_*)^TA(x-x_*) + 2b^Tx + x_*Ax_*.
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\phi(x) &= \frac 12 (x-x_*)^TA(x-x_*) + b^Tx + \frac 12 x_*Ax_* - b^Tx
\\ & = \frac 12 (x - x_*)^TA(x - x_*) + \frac 12 x_*Ax_*.
\end{align}
$$
Note that $x_*Ax_*$ is constant. Because $A$ is positive semidefinite, we can therefore see from the above that $\phi(x)$ is minimized when $(x-x_*)^TA(x - x_*)$ attains its minimal value of $0$, and this minimum occurs when $x = x_*$.

In other words, $x_*$ (the solution to $Ax = b$) is the value at which the minimum is attained.

Comment: Thanks you so much!